# Reference for the Hilbert scheme of points as GIT quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

Could you provide me some ressources concerning the construction of the Hilbert scheme of n ponts in $\mathbb{C} ^2$ as a GIT quotient.
There is this [article](https://web.northeastern.edu/iloseu/Barbara_14_complete.pdf) of Barbara Bolognese and Ivan Losev but the proof of the proposition 3.4 doesn't prove the good inclusion or at least, I don't understand it.
Best, Rhylx

Comment: What is a GIT quotient ? Can you provide references ?

Comment: Did you look into the book of Nakajima?

Comment: @JeanMarie please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIT_quotient. The canonical reference is Mumford's https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540569633

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Sasha What is the title of Nakajima's book, please?

Comment: @user2831784: "Lectures on Hilbert schemes of points on surfaces".

Comment: Thanks @Sasha for this reference. In fact Nakajima is building the Hilbert scheme of points as a quotient and it overlaps pretty well with the article of Bolognese and Losev but he doesn't speak about the link with the $det^{-1}$ semi-stable points. Do you know  a reference that speaks about that too?